# What is the difference between $f(x_1) \geq f(x_2)$ and $(f(x_1) > f(x_2))$?

Tags: functions

I am studying for my math course and I come across this definition. [image]

I am really struggling to understand the difference the parentheses make in the inequality. Can somebody please explain and why?

Thank you.

Comment: Where do you see `(f(x))` in the text?

Comment: Sorry what I meant is what is the difference between f(x1) > f(x2) and (f(x1) > f(x2)). Like what difference does the fact that the f(x1) > f(x2) are closed in the parentheses make? (the right part of the inequality)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're misreading. This whole paragraph follows the general pattern for saying two similar things at the same time.

> ____ X (or Y) ____ P (or Q) ____

which means both

> ____ X ____ P ____

and

> ____ Y ____ Q ____

The first inequality is only meant to appear in the first meaning, and the second (parenthesized) inequality is only meant to appear in the second meaning.

Comment: the number of blah's make this oddly difficult to read

Comment: @user363464: I agree and appreciate the second opinion!

Comment: This makes perfect sense, thank you very much :)

Comment: Use `If` and `then` instead of `____`?

Comment: This is probably a matter of personal taste but I tend to prefer the use of  _respectively Y_ rather than _or Y_. I think that the latter can be a bit misleading in some cases.

Answer (score 4):

This is a shortcut used by many textbooks. We define both decreasing and strictly decreasing at the same time. Because their definitions are the same, except for the $\geq$ and $>$, the author used parentheses to differentiate between the two cases.

Comment: omg thank you very much, I always tend to mess up like this :)